# Why is this line of code giving me an error?

Tags: android

I am trying to loop through a vectors elements and trying to find out if a position in the vector is equal to null...

```
if(_vecForShapes.get(i)!=null)//this line works fine but when it gets to a position where        it is null it gives me an error? Any ideas?
{

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You said you want to find out if a position is equal to null, so why are you using "is not equal to"?

Comment: I don't know what `_vecForShapes` is, but it is document that `get` with an invalid index returns `null`? If not, you have no reason to expect that behavior.

Comment: What the error? StackTrace? May be your object _vecForShapes is null, and when you try to get ".get(i)" something from it you get an error.

Comment: try (null != _vecForShapes.get(i)). Maybe I am going crazy, but I seem to recall it not wanting to do the comparison because the get(i) is returning null. Is the exception you are a NullPointer?

Comment: Thanks Tim, this still throws an error though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that it is get(i) that is null, and not that you have exceeded the number of items in _vecForShapes?  It is much more likely that the _vecForShapes.get(i) is throwing an error than the comparison to null.

What type does get(i) return?

Comment: So I have stepped through the code...I have 2 elements in vecForShapes...I want to execute the code in the if statement for these two elements then when the 3rd is null I want to skip the if block...I have also tried the function .elementAt(i);

Comment: Can you post the code for your loop?

Comment: @JamesHatton: There is no third element. You say "the third is null", but it is not. It does not exist at all. Unless `get` is specifically documents to return `null` with a bad index, you should not expect it to do so. (Perhaps it throws an exception. Perhaps it's UB. Who knows?)

Comment: What does your for statement look like? Is there a specific reason you can't loop through the size/length of vecForShapes and need to check for the 3rd element?